# How to trace number of duplicate data in 2D Array in flex

Tags: apache-flex, multidimensional-array

I have a data as follows:

```
Chennai 11  10
Mumbai  12  20
Mumbai  22  40
Calcutta 4  35
Calcutta 3  50
Chennai 13  45
Calcutta 4  55
Mumbai   5  50
```

I need to get an array which gives chennai:2 mumbai:3 calcutta:3.

How to get this?

Comment: What have you tried?  What is your underlying ActionScript structure?  Are you using Struct's or an Array of Arrays?  To my knowledge there is no easy function to parse an array and look for duplicate items.

Comment: @Reboog711  The above data is a 2D array.I need the count of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the data; and save it as a Associative Array.  I'd use a Dictionary.  Conceptually, like this:

```
var dict :Dictionary = new Dictionary();

for (var x:int; x<your2DArray.length;x++){
  var stringToExamine :String = your2DArray[x][1];
  if(dict.hasOwnProperty(stringToExamine)){
    dict[stringToExamine] ++;
  } else {
    dict[stringToExamine] = 1;
  }
}
```

Now you said you want this as an array, so you'll have to convert the Dictionary object to an array somehow.  Presumably another 2 dimensional array.

```
var newArray :Array = new Array();
var counter :int = 0;
for each (var key :String in dict) 
{ 
    newArray[counter] = [key,dict[key]];
    counter++;
}
```

I wrote this code in a browser; so it may have issues. But, the algorithm should be solid.

Comment: could you pl help me without using dictionary concept?I tried above code but unable to get the output,also not familiar with dictionary concept.

Comment: Read about Dictionary here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html and Associative Arrays: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eea.html . I see no easy way to accomplish your task without using a Dictionary.

Comment: I need to learn about Dictionary concept in detail.I referred those docs and searched examples on it but could not find much those that are understandable.Thanks for the above answer.I will surely get to know the above concept.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to form a single dimensional array("arr" in below example) from 2D array taking first column of 2D array.
The second step is to form another new single dimensional array removing duplicates("dupe" in below example).
The third step is to increment a integer variable on comparison of both the array data as follows and finally pushing the integer variable into another new array.

Let me have the following array:

```
 private var arr:Array = new Array('Chennai', 
                'Mumbai',  
                'Mumbai',  
                'Calcutta', 
                'Calcutta', 
                'Chennai',
                'Calcutta', 
                'Mumbai',
                'Kerala',
                'Kerala',
                'Kerala',
                'Kerala',
                'US');

 private var dupe:Array = new Array('Chennai', 
            'Mumbai',  
            'Calcutta',
                                     'Kerala',
             'US');

 var aNewArr:Array = new Array(new Array());
 var repeatedFinalArray:Array = new Array();

 for(var a:int=0; a<dupe.length;a++)
 {
 var count:int=0;
 for(var j:int=0;j<arr.length;j++)
 {
   if(dupe[a]==arr[j])
  {
     count++;
  }
}
aNewArr.push([dupe[a]],[count]);
repeatedFinalArray.push(count);
  }

The output of aNewArr will have:
Chennai,2,Mumbai,3,Calcutta,3,Kerala,4,US,1
and 
repeatedFinalArray will have jus the counts : 2,3,3,4,1
```